# Equivalent definintion of "sorting" for functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lie-groups, computer-science

In computer science suppose you've an array $A = \left\{a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{N-1} \right\}$. A common algorithm usually taught is sorting which returns a permutation $\pi : \left\{0,\ldots N-1\right\} \to \left\{0,\ldots N-1\right\}$ such that $A = \left\{a_{\pi(0)},a_{\pi(1)},\ldots,a_{\pi(N-1)} \right\}$ with $a_{\pi(i)} \leq a_{\pi(i+1)}$ for $i = 0,\ldots,N-2$.

Now the array $A$ can be seen as a function $A : \left\{0,\ldots,N-1 \right\} \to \mathbb{R}$ and the sorting can be seen as an operator on such function.

What I wonder is there's an equivalent of such operator, or it can be defined, on some function space $X$. I know Lie groups are an equivalent of rotation, which generalize permutations, but I don't know about the sorting though.